# Adding columns using column aliases

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering if we can't add the columns with their aliases.

For eg;

```
select header_id h,org_id o, (h+o)hi from oe_order_headers_all
```

This gives me error. Is there anyway to do it without having to refer the full column name. I am showing an example here but when a column is being derived from a function it's usually big so we use alias and now I want the derived column aliases to be used for other things.

Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: You may use such column aliases in ORDER BY and in the parent query. So you can do something like this: "select h, o, (h+o) hi from (select header_id h,org_id o from oe_order_headers_all)"

Comment: What version of Oracle?  If you're using a recent version, you may be able to create a virtual column (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php).

Answer (score 2):

This gives you an error because you cannot use a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.  You can, however, use a subquery or CTE:

```
select h, o, (h + o) as hi 
from (select header_id as h, org_id as o
      from oe_order_headers_all
     ) oha;
```

There should be no additional overhead to using the subquery.  You can also do this with a CTE:

```
with oha as (
      select header_id as h, org_id as o
      from oe_order_headers_all
     )
select h, o, (h + o) as hi 
from oha;
```

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. But I guess I have to deal with writing a function and using the full names instead of aliases as I have a big query which uses functions to get few columns data and writing a subquery in the select statement might make it work slow.

Comment: @Sandy . . . The subquery is either a CTE or in a subquery and probably would not affect performance in Oracle.